# The elements of a closed set and compact set form a closed set.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, compactness

Let $A$ be a compact subset and $B$ be a closed subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

> Prove that the subset $\alpha A+B$ (which is defined as $\{ \alpha a+b: a \in A, b \in B, \alpha \in [-3,2] \}$) is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

**My Attempt:** First $\alpha$ is a closed set and $A$ is closed by the Heine-Borel theorem.

Let $x$ be a limit point of $\alpha A+B$. Then there exists a sequence $\{p_i: i\in \mathbb{N} \}$ in $\alpha A+B$ which converges to $x$. Now suppose $x \not \in \alpha A+B$. Let $\epsilon = \Vert x- (\alpha a+b) \Vert $. Since $\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty}p_i=x$, there exists $N$ such $i>N$ implies $\vert x - p_i\Vert < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Since $\Vert x- p_i \Vert \geq \epsilon$ we have a contradiction. Then $x$ must belong to $\alpha A+B$ . Hence as $\alpha A+B$ contains its limit points it is closed.

Any comments on my anwser would be appreciated.

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$ when you first define $\epsilon$?

Comment: where does that $\alpha\in [-3,2]$ come from? Looks strange to me. You should write $[-3,2]A+B$ for $\bigcup_{\alpha\in[-3,2]} \alpha A + B$ if you need to. As for you question: Where do $a$ and $b$ come from? Better: Assume $x_n \in M=\alpha A + B$ with $x_n\to x$ and show that $x\in M$.

Comment: @user251257  I thought it was clear from the question but let me clarify. $\alpha$ is defined as being any element of the closed set $[-3,2]$. $a$ and $b$ are any elements in $A$ and $B$ respectively. Note that in the context of this question $A+B$ does not mean union by the element wise addition as given by the question (That is any element in \alpha times any element a + any element b makes the elements of the set).  So when I define $\epsilon$ I am using the $a$ and $b$ from the definition of the set.

Comment: @Nitin See above comment.

Comment: When you're defining $\epsilon$ you need to chose a specific $a\in A$ and $b \in B$. Can't be all of them.

Comment: @AzJ: As for notation, you shouldn't write $\alpha A + B$ for $\{ \alpha a + b \mid \alpha\in[-3,2], a\in A, b\in B \}$, as $\alpha$ isn't free.

Comment: Okay now it makes more sense. Also the definition for $\alpha a+b$ is just the way it is written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M = \{ \alpha a + b \mid \alpha\in [-3,2], a\in A, b\in B \}$, $x_n\in M$ and $x_n\to x$.

**Hints:**

1. There exist $\alpha_n\in [-3,2]$, $a_n\in A$, and $b_n\in B$ with $x_n = \alpha_n a_n + b_n$.
2. As $[-3,2]$ and $A$ are compact, there are convergent subsequences, say  $\alpha_{n_k}\to \alpha^* \in [-3,2]$ and $a_{n_k} \to a^* \in A$.
3. Show that the subsequence $b_{n_k}$ converges and has limit $b^*\in B$.
4. Thus, $x = \alpha^* a^* + b^* \in M$.